# Loading user control dynamically loses data

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a created a user control. This user control I dynamically load on a page inside Telerik  Panelbar control. I have done all necessary coding to save the viewstate and load this dynamically created usercontrol every time page loads.
On this User control I have a asp panel. By default this panel is invisible. When user clicks a button on this user control panel is made visible.  On page load of this user control I populate all the controls on this panel.
Everything works fine if I don’t  load this use control dynamically but when I load this user control dynamically  and if I make panel visible by default then only all fields on the panel are populated. But if I make by default invisible and on button click make panel visible none of the text boxes or comboboxes are populated. 
I populate comboboxes on page load of the userControl but inbetween  postbacks all the comboboxes on the user control loose data.
ON the parent page I am saving the viewstate 
This is my code on parent page to dynamically load userControl  ( which has panel on it)
Dim ucPiggyBank As SubscriberSetupPages_UserControls_PiggyBank = CType(LoadControl("~/SubscriberSetupPages/UserControls/PiggyBank.ascx"), SubscriberSetupPages_UserControls_PiggyBank)
        With ucPiggyBank
            .PiggyBankID = account.Id
            .ID = account.Id.ToString
            'Setting up following 3 properties here to avoid database trips
            .PiggyBankEligibleAccounts = piggyBankEligibleAccountCollection
            .MemorizedNames = memorizednames
            .Period = period
        End With
        radPanelNewChild.Controls.Add(ucPiggyBank)
        radPanelNew.Items.Add(radPanelNewChild)
        radPanelNew.Expanded = True
‘this is the Panel item on parent page of Telerik Panelbar control.
Dim radPanelPiggyBank As RadPanelItem = DirectCast(pnlbarPiggyBank.FindItemByValue("TestItem"), RadPanelItem)
        With radPanelPiggyBank
            .Items.Add(radPanelNew)
            .DataBind()
        End With
‘I am doing everything for saving viewstate on parent control
This is the code on page load of userControl
    If Not IsPostBack Then

```
        If m_PiggyBankID <> Guid.Empty Then
            'Load data
            Call GetPiggyBankDetails()
        End If
```

I have a edit button on the user control which makes panel visible.  It makes panel visible but with no data.
Can you please tell me what’s happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If data is posted, you can get it from Request.Form[control.UniqueID] , but don't use viewstate possibilities hehe if control added dynamically.

Comment: What I am trying to do is show all details when edit button on user control is clicked ( whic are on asp Panel) on first load these are populated. But when I make visible on edit click they are not populated any more. But By default if I keep panel visible I do see all controls populated. It means that post back sent by edit button is loosing the data. Which it should not. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Basically if you need to start editing control populate fields by assigning them value from Request.Form | That means if you have control txtName you can populate from Form like this txtName.Text = Request.Form[txtName.UniqueID].ToString(); Basically if you are adding controls dynamically than there is no view state for that control, but you can also access existing view state using ViewState["name"]

Comment: how to populate those controls is not an issue here. I populate them on page load in INVISIBLE panel. When I make PANEL VISIBLE by button click. controls should be just visible with prepopulated values on page load. I am just making panel visible nothing else. But all text boxes come empty. Why should I repopulate them? I know with post back page is re written compeltly with values saves in viewsatate.